# how to set a widget's size in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

simple example:

```
from tkinter import *

class GUI_CMP():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.text = Text(self.tk,width=60,height=40)
        self.text.pack()

        self.tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui_cmp = GUI_CMP()
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

As you can see,though I set `width=60,height=40`,the width of text widget is smaller than its height.This keeps disturbing me every time I use tkinter.So my questions are:

1. What exactly does `40` and `60` mean?
2. What is the reason that text's width is smaller than its height?
3. What is the best way to do size controll?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when you specify the width and height they aren't in pixels;
they are measured by characters and lines depending on the current font size

that's why when you do `Text(self.tk,width=60,height=40)` the 60 means the text widget is 60 characters wide and the 40 means its 40 lines high

this also applies to Buttons

that's where the confusion comes from, because its not in pixels and if you change the font it ill change the size of the text widget!

and that's probably the best way to do size control its just confusing at first but now that you know it will make more sense!

take a look at this site [Text Widget Info](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_text.htm) and look through the parameters for more information

Comment: pretty much any widget that uses text (message, button, text,etc) are all measure like that but something like canvas will be measured using pixels :)