# set constant size for widget and align text inside the widget, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, alignment

Didn't see it here nor in the documentation. 
Is there any way to set a conatant size for widgets and also align the text inside the widget to be centered?

I have an OptionMenu changing sizes by option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is decided by the text size in your Widget. This question has already been answered in Stackoverflow. You can find it here:

[how to set a widget's size in tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398926/how-to-set-a-widgets-size-in-tkinter)

Comment: Thank you, didn't find it before, waiting a few minutes so i can close this